# how to insert multiple lines repeatedly in a SQL file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In a SQL file, is it possible to insert multiple lines in multiple queries all at once?  For example, I have a stored procedure SQL file that has several queries.  Each query writes into a table the exact same way.  It writes in the following way:

```
INSERT INTO some_table
SELECT
'some_value' AS column1,
'some_other_value' AS column2,
'another_value' AS column3
FROM source_table
....
```

I'm trying to add the following lines between the last column and the FROM clause:

```
'stuff' AS column4,
'more_stuff' AS column5
```

So, the final query will look like:

```
INSERT INTO some_table
SELECT
'some_value' AS column1,
'some_other_value' AS column2,
'another_value' AS column3,
'stuff' AS column4,
'more_stuff' AS column5
FROM source_table
....
```

While I can do this manually, it will be very time-consuming to do it for every query.  Is there a way to do it for all queries at once?

In the find-replace method, I don't think I can do the following:

1) Find all lines that read
`'some_stuff'`

2) Replace each of the identified lines with the following set of multiple lines:

```
   'some_stuff'
   'more_stuff'
   'yet_more_stuff'
```

Comment: So you're trying to edit the system table that has the code in it, is that correct?

Comment: is it possible to insert multiple lines in multiple queries all at once?  Yep.  You could write a procedure that retreives the source code for each query from a system table.  Parse that sql to find the relavant columns and use substrings to basically do the addition and then recompile the SQL created dynamically.  If you have hundreds of queries, and they all have the same format it might be worth the time to use automation.  Otherwise manual is likely going to be faster especially if you export each one and do a "find/Replace" SHOULD you edit code this way?  as long as each one is tested ok.

Comment: The definition for some_table was already changed to consume the new columns.

Comment: Since you say you want to edit a SQL file, I'm going to take you literally and suggest you open the file in SSMS and try ctrl-h.

Comment: The problem with the Find-Replace method (as far as I know) is that it only works for identifying 1 chunk of text and replacing it with another chunk of text that doesn't span multiple lines.

Comment: you can insert the new fields just before FROM (in the same line). if your tool uses \n for line endings you can replace "FROM" with ", fieldx, fieldy\n FROM"